# Resize a div and jump to next column/div

Tags: javascript, html, resize, drag

How can I jump a resized div to next row when the resize is constrained on the parent div like below (fullcalendar like thing).

Update.*This code is dependent on InteractJS (http://interactjs.io/)*

```
interact(resizeDiv)
    .resizable({
        edges: { left: true, right: true, bottom: false, top: false },

        restrictEdges: {
          endOnly: true,
          outer: '.month'
        },

        restrictSize: {
          min: { width: 80, height: 3 },
          max: {height: 3}
        },

        inertia: true,
      })
      .on('resizemove', function (event) {
        var target = event.target,
            x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0),
            y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);
        target.style.width  = event.rect.width + 'px';
        target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';

        x += event.deltaRect.left;
        y += event.deltaRect.top;

        target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform =
            'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';

        target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
        target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
        target.textContent = Math.round(event.rect.width) + '\u00D7' + Math.round(event.rect.height);
        var onTopElement = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);

        let calendarArea = document.getElementById('calendarArea');
        console.log(event.clientY, target.offsetTop);
      })
```

Example - Fullcalendar:
[image: Example - Fullcalendar]

Comment: Do you have any sample code that we can view so we can see what you've made so far?

Comment: @fixatd I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Fullcalendar logic is simple, it will create a new div on next row rather than using the same div which you are resizing and apply resize(for fullcalendar, it uses JQuery resize event) event on the new div. I think its technically impossible to use the same div(same dom element) on the two rows which you are trying to do.